# pgfmathsetcounter to unprecise

Tags: pgfmath, arithmetic

I want to use the following commman

```
\newcommand{\Gewicht}[2]{
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd, precision=8}
    Volumen des Bauteils nach CAD: \SI{#1}{\cm^3}\\
    Dichte: \SI{#2}{\kg\per\cm^3}\\
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Masse}{#1*#2}
    Gewicht: $\SI{#1}{\cm^3} \cdot \SI{#2}{\kg\per\cm^3}$ = \SI[round-mode=places, round-precision=4]{\Masse}{\kg}\\
    \begin{flushright}
        \underline{\SI[round-mode=places, round-precision=4]{\Masse}{\Kg}}
    \end{flushright}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Gesamt}{\Masse*\Anzahl}
    \immediate\write\weightfile{\Bauteilname & \Anzahl & \num[round-mode=places, round-precision=4]{\Gesamt} \detokenize{\\ \hline}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Flugzeuggewicht}{\Flugzeuggewicht+\Gesamt}
}
```

If I now run `\Gewicht{705.5634}{0.0027}`
\Masse is 1.9056, roundet it schould be 1.9050.
I know this is due to flowtigpoint percision.
What I don't know is if there is a way to fix this.
How can I get a Result that alsway is accurat to the 4th decimal Place.

Ps.: Shouldn't numbers with a float arithmetic have percision to the 5th decimal place?

Comment: Who says pdfmathmath has floating point precision? The fp package might be better

Comment: And please extend your example to something others can copy and test as is.

Comment: @daleif fp package worked for me thak you

Comment: Note that the fp stuff might actually already be in modern kernels using the expl3 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The `xfp` package is literally made for this kind of calculations.

Comment: don't you mean xfp (or \fpeval)?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, fixed